# No plugin found for prefix 'spring' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Getting below error after doing mvn spring:boot run   :

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring' in the current project and in the 
    plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the 
    repositories [local (/path/to/local/repo), spring-snapshots 
    (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot), spring-milestones 
    (http://repo.spring.io/milestone), central 
    (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

My pom.xml is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
<!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId> <artifactId>maven-common-artifact-filters</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.1</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried doing mvn clean install and then mvn spring:boot run but no luck..

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run` see [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-with-the-maven-plugin).

Comment: You should start using a repository manager and not defining the repositories in your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise How do you start using a repository manager?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the command is `mvn spring-boot:run`